# sizeof operator return in 16bit processor system

Tags: c

What would sizeof operator return for int data type in 16bit processor system ?

I'm thinking it would be 2 bytes since that's max int that can be represented in system

Comment: This is usually the case, but the standard has no rule about the size of `int`

Comment: The hardware doesn't limit the size of numeric types. Consider GCC's `__float128` type, which works even on platforms that have no instructions for manipulating them (e.g. x86_64).

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes it does. At least 16 bits. But no upper limit.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Well ok. Then I just say that it is impossible to conform to the standard with a size for `int` smaller than 15 bits

Comment: @klutt, yes, sorry, I misread your comment, I need holydays :) you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is about C and not C++. They are two different languages. It may or may not be applicable to C++.

The only thing the standard says about the size is that it should be at least 16 bits. It has nothing to do with the hardware. A compiler may use 16-bit ints on a 32 bit system. The hardware does not dictate this. The compiler constructors typically make optimizations towards certain hardware for obvious reasons, but they are not required to.

An int should be able to hold all values in the range [-32767, 32767], although it's common with [-3276**8**, 32767] on 16 bit systems that are using two complement representation, which almost all modern system does.